# How to truncate text in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to show smaller text. I see options like making custom pipe for truncating string but my case is different as follows.

```
<p [innerHTML]="aboutUs"></p>
```

In this I can't use a custom pipe. I'm doing this because I show text from backend & it comes with tags that's why [innerHtml] is used. Please help.

Comment: You don't have *text* then. You have an HTML snippet. If this HTML can contain anything, truncating it while keeping it valid is quite hard. And even then, if it's only constituted of `<br/>`or small `<p>`, then it will takes a lot more vertical space than text. Why do you store and display HTML? What does this HTML contain? Where does it come from? What's the goal in truncating it? Can't you simply put it in a scrollable div? Details matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do with a custom function using TypeScript as,

```
truncateChar(text: string): string {
    let charlimit = 100;
    if(!text || text.length <= charlimit )
    {
        return text;
    }

  let without_html = text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
  let shortened = without_html.substring(0, charlimit) + "...";
  return shortened;
}
```

and in the HTML refer it as,

```
<div [innerHTML]="truncateChar(aboutUs)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using a method call from `HTML` template as it will be called a lot of times, which would be unnecessary processing if the desired result is static or not modified very often.

Call the method truncateChar(in **@Sajeetharan** answer) from any of ngOnInit, ngOnChange or wherever you are updating the `aboutUs` variable and save the result in some variable in that component.

**Use this variable in your template instead of calling the method directly.**